# Parsing the response from a jQuery ajax form post

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I am successfully posting a form via ajax, using the following code;

```
 $.post( "Page.do?source=ajax", 
            $("#Form").serialize(), 
            function(data){ 


                }
```

The data response that comes back can be alert'd. I can see that it is the HTML of the entire form, having been submitted. But, I am having trouble accessing an element in that form which has come via ajax, ie

```
data.find('.Errors').html()
```

or

```
$('.Errors', data).html()
```

Do I need to somehow convert the text into a DOM which can then be parsed by jQuery?

Comment: first you need to convert it to a jQuery object, but even after that .find() might not work see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8612928/1404348 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/405700/1404348

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, otherwise you would have to apply regex to the result (which is a string and not a DOM).

You can convert it to DOM by:

```
$(data)
```

and then applying any jQuery you want to it.

Comment: @Andy: The example @prodigitalson gave should work: $(data).find('.Errors').html(); assuming that your data is valid HTML.

Comment: hmm, removing elements from $(data) is more difficult but I've got it to work, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to somehow convert the text into a DOM which can then be parsed by jQuery?

Yes you do:

`$(data).find('.Errors').html();`

Although normally using data as the scope for the selector like you showed in your second example should work.

Comment: .find() might not work see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8612928/1404348 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/405700/1404348