# jQuery .find() on data from .ajax() call is returning "[object Object]" instead of div

Tags: jquery, ajax, find

Trying to find `div` element with `id="result"` in returned data from `.ajax()` using `.find()`. Unfortunately, `alert(result)` doesn't return `div#result`.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url, 
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        result = $(response).find("#result");
        alert(response); // works as expected (returns all html)
        alert(result); // returns [object Object]
    }
});
```

Comment: does the response come in the fist place: `alert(response)`?

Comment: I don't know how to fix your code in the way you did, but I think it will work if you first put the content inside a div tag with display none and then find the #result tag inside this div. Like: $('#div-content').html(result); $('#div-content').find('#result');

Answer (score 111, accepted):

To answer your question specifically, it seems to be working correctly. You said that it returns `[object Object]`, which is what jQuery will return with the `find("#result")` method. It returns a jQuery element that matches the `find` query.

Try getting an attribute of that object, like `result.attr("id")` - it should return `result`.

---

In general, this answer depends on whether or not `#result` is the top level element.

If `#result` is the top level element,

```
<!-- #result as top level element -->
<div id="result">
  <span>Text</span>
</div>
<div id="other-top-level-element"></div>
```

`find()` will not work. Instead, use `filter()`:

```
var $result = $(response).filter('#result');
```

If `#result` is not the top level element,

```
<!-- #result not as top level element -->
<div>
  <div id="result">
    <span>Text</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

`find()` will work:

```
var $result = $(response).find('#result');
```

Comment: Was just figuring out how to do this on my own - this definitely has saved me some time :)

Comment: This saved me as well.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I found a simple comparison that can be helpful http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/difference-between-filter-and-find-in-jquery/

Comment: so this will always work.  $("<div>"+response+"</div>").find('#result');

Comment: Arg, the behavior difference between .find and .filter really bothers me sometimes. But thank you for this answer which covers both and why to use one or need one.

Comment: Thanks a lot...@stephen

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Never knew of the jquery filter method, that helps when storing HTML in javascript variables outside of the DOM.

Answer (score 29):

I just spent 3 hours to solve a similar problem. This is what worked for me.

The element that I was attempting to retrieve from my `$.get` response was a first child element of the body tag. For some reason when I wrapped a div around this element, it became retrievable through `$(response).find('#nameofelement')`.

No idea why but yeah, retrievable element cannot be first child of body... that might be helpful to someone :)

Comment: Actually i think this should have been validated as the correct answer

Comment: this is a better solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/13875063/1404348 and worked for me.

Comment: this solution worked for me as i had 2 divs being returned as parents. after wrapping them in a single container, the returned html became searchable and traversable.

Comment: Wrapping the element around a div did the trick, this should be the correct answer!

Answer (score 21):

try this:

```
result = $("#result", response);
```

btw `alert` is a rough way to debug things, try `console.log`

Comment: Don't know why but $("#result").replaceWith($(html).find("#result")); didn't work and your answer worked nicely !

Answer (score 8):

this is your answer:

```
<div class="test">Hello</div>
<div class="one">World</div>
```

The following jQuery Won't work:

```
$(data).find('div.test');
```

as the divs are top level elements and data isn't an element but a string, to make it work you need to use .filter

```
$(data).filter('div.test');
```

Another same question: 
[Use Jquery Selectors on $.AJAX loaded HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405409/use-jquery-selectors-on-ajax-loaded-html)

Comment: I think, this is the best answer

Comment: This also seems to work if `.find()` gives you too many or wrong results.

Answer (score 6):

do not forget to do it with parse html. like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url, 
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        var parsed = $.parseHTML(response);
        result = $(parsed).find("#result");
    }
});
```

has to work :)

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me, you just need to put .html() on the end of - $(response).find("#result")

Comment: People have not written this useful .html() method to prevent [object object] in alert box. you have mentioned it and this worked 4 me. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The jQuery find() is returning a jQuery object that wraps the DOM object. You should be able to work with that object to do what you'd like with the div.

Comment: stjowa beat me to it. It looks like it's working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that your **ajax** ***response*** is returning a ***string***, so if you use directly **$(response)** it would return **JQUERY:** *Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression* in the console. In order to use it properly you need to use first a JQUERY built-in function called [**$.parseHTML(response)**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/). As what the function name implies you need to parse the string first as an **html object**. Just like this in your case:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url, 
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        var parsedResponse = $.parseHTML(response);
        var result = $(parsedResponse).find("#result");

        alert(response); // returns as string in console
        alert(parsedResponse); // returns as object HTML in console
        alert(result); // returns as object that has an id named result 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify `dataType: "html"`.

If you do not jQuery will guess the requested data type (check: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). My guess is that in your case `response` was a `String` rather than a `DOMObject`. Obviously DOM methods won't work on a String.

You could test that with `console.log("type of response: " + typeof response)` (or `alert("type of response:" + typeof response)`, in case you don't run Firebug)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in this way to find any div and get its attributes or anything you want.

```
$(response).filter('#elementtobefindinresponse').attr("id");
```

or

```
$(response).filter('img#test').attr("src");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `#result` in the response HTML? Try the following. jQuery will still return an empty object if it doesn't find anything.

```
alert(result.length);
```

Comment: return 1 but how to get html of that div

Answer (score 0):

You should add `dataType: "html"` to the request. Im quite sure you wont be able to search the DOM of the returned html if it doesnt know it is html.

Comment: I had a related problem that this didn't solve. I was retrieving an entire web page via AJAX, and either due to a <!doctype> tag or some other malformed issue, jQuery saw the response as a array of text nodes instead of a proper DOM tree. The solution for me was simplifying the response nodes.

Answer (score 0):

you just use the following code

```
var response= $(result);

$(response).find("#id/.class").html(); [or] $($(result)).find("#id/.class").html();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false,
    success: function(response) {
        $('.element').html(response);
    }
});

< span class = "element" >
    //response
    < div id = "result" >
        Not found 
    </div> 
</span>

var result = $("#result:contains('Not found')").text();
console.log(result); // output: Not found
```

Answer (score 0):

try 
    if( $(response).filter('#result').length )
        // do something

Answer (score 0):

To view the content in alert use:

`alert( $(response).find("#result").html() );`

Answer (score -1):

You might have to do something like

```
var content= (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d
```

then you should be able to use

```
result = $(content).find("#result")
```

Comment: This will work for sure if you are using a web service, and your data type is 'json'