# <li>'s on the ajax response doesn't count for some reason

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using the following script:

```
$.ajax({
    url: urls.notifications,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'html',
    data: {timestamp: notification_timestamp},
    success: function(response) {
        var responseAmt = $(response).find("li").length;
        alert(responseAmt);
    }
});
```

This is the response I get:

```
<li class="notification" data-notification-id="117">

    <a href="http://local.dev/user/admin">
        <div class="avatar-container">
            <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/64e1b8d34f425d19e1ee2ea7236d3028">
        </div>
    </a>
    <div class="content">
        <p class="message">

                                                <a href="http://local.dev/user/admin"><b>admin</b></a> has commented on your post.                  
                <a href="http://local.dev/gag/image-example-10">
                    <b>Check it out</b>!
                </a>

        </p>
        <p class="timestamp">
            <i class="fa fa-clock-o fa-fw"></i>
            5 seconds ago           </p>
    </div>
</li>
```

Each response can contain 1 or many `<li>`'s like that, and I need to count them to update `responseAmt` variable, which holds the amount of notifications returned.

I tried:

```
$(response).find("li").size(); //shows 0
$(response).find("li").length; //shows 0
```

But this one works correctly:

```
$(response).find(".content").length; //shows correct amount
```

Anyone knows why I can't count `<li>`'s?

Comment: Then Use `$(response).find(".notification").length;` insted of `$(response).find("li").length;`

Comment: @joker: Why should that make a difference? If the element cannot be found via its tag name, why should be found via its class name?

Comment: I did not read the html response from ajax ever but out of curiosity from your code; you are reading .content which is a class for div; is it possible to read <li> by it's class name? or do u have different classes for <li>.

Comment: @FelixKling, In que he says that `$(response).find(".content").length;` //shows correct amount
then he can also find a correct value from class

Comment: Is the <li> first element in body. see this might be the reason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300332/jquery-find-on-data-from-ajax-call-is-returning-object-object-instead

Comment: @joker: But `.notification` is the class of the `li` element itself. If an element cannot be found via its tag name, then its impossible to find it via its class name.

Comment: @FelixKling yes what ever the tag name you can find from class name as altnative.

Comment: @joker: I don't think you understand what I mean, maybe I'm not clear enough. See my answer for the reason why `$(response).find("li")` doesn't work. That's why `$(response).find(".notification")` wouldn't work either.

Comment: @FelixKling i got it your are right, but i think if you can use a `$(response).find(".content").length;`, where .content is class of div. then whtevr LI is selector or not.it can be find from its class also.

Comment: @joker: Yes, if every `li` element contains only one element with class `content`, that would work as well.

Comment: @FelixKling ok. . .and your ans is right,so no need to work with class name. so leave it, and pleasure to conversation with u.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `li` elements seem to be the **selected** nodes. `.find` searches **inside** those nodes. I.e. `$(response).find("li")` searches for `li` elements inside those `li` elements (which don't exist).

You can use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead, but if know that the top level nodes in the response are always going to be `li` elements anyway, just access `.length` directly:

```
$(response).length
```

Comment: Yes. Top level element is always going to be `li`. Thanks for providing two different solutions. :) Will pick this as the correct answer in few minutes.

Ps. My remaining unripped hair thanks you.

Comment: @Aristona: Tell your hair it was my pleasure ;)