# Count an element after jquery .get

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code which gets the html from another page

```
    $.get('alertjquery.html', null, function(tsv) {
     alert(tsv);
});
```

what I want to do know is count for the number of a certain element thats in the html page. 
I am a bit confused as if i did `var data $('section').length;` it wouldn't count the sections in the `tsv` but the sections in the current html page

this is the html page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = $('#test').text($('section').length);
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
 <section>
 This should be counted
 </section>
 <section>
 This should be counted
 </section>
 <section>
 This should be counted
 </section>
 <section>
 This should be counted
 </section>
 <section>
 This should be counted
 </section>

  There are currently <b id='test'></b> alerts


</body>
</html>
```

When I alert this as tsv this also gets printed out
However when I tried $tsv.find("section").length it returns 0

Comment: 1. close your HTML tag </html>, 2. it should be alert($(tsv).find("section").length)

Comment: exact duplicate of [<li>'s on the ajax response doesn't count for some reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22138760/lis-on-the-ajax-response-doesnt-count-for-some-reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work in all cases, even `tsv` isn't a container:

```
$('<div/>', {
    html: tsv
}).find('section').length;
```

Comment: +1 because of the nice syntax and the solution works for all use cases.

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the HTML received with jQuery, and then use whatever jQuery function you want on it:

```
$(tsv).find("section").length
```

EDIT:
if your tsv content isn't wrapped by `<html>` or some other container (which implies it's not a "valid" html document), you can do the following:

```
$("<div>"+tsv+"</div>").find("section").length
```

Comment: won't work if e.g `tsv = "<section></section>";` You should then use `.filter()`

Comment: I agree, but in most use cases, especially if the guy goes to another HTML page, the content will be wrapped in <html> and then it will work. Your solution is good also for the cases his content isn't a valid HTML page.

Comment: Ok, i see my bad! `'alertjquery.html'`  +1 ;)

Comment: $.get('alertjquery.html') in his code tells me it's an html page. Now - I agree that it might be just a name and this isn't a real html document, but... most of the chances it is.