# jQuery AJAX response find div returns Null

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have a table that gets sorted by a certain column when the user selects an option from the drop-down.  It is a self-referencing PHP script that contains an IF clause for a GET request.

Since it is a self-referencing file, it returns the entire HTML content of the page, so I need a single div returned.  The entire response returns fine, but jQuery find always returns null for any div.

Also, the response data always returns "string" even though I have specified html.  I'm not sure if this is relevant or not.

This is what I have so far:

```
function sortTable()
{     
    var by=encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("sort").value)
    $.ajax({
    type: "GET", 
    url: '/tasks?sort=', 
    data: by,  
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {  
        var tmp = data;
        var test = $(tmp).find("sort-table");
        alert(test.html());


    },

    });
```

Comment: what is sort-table? is it id,class or tag?

Comment: sort-table is an id, I have tried using #sort-table without any luck

Comment: You probably have another element with the same id somewhere on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something

```
var test = $(tmp).find(".sort-table");
```

or

```
var test = $(tmp).find("#sort-table");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = $(tmp).find("div.sort-table");
```

it will find `div`s with class `sort-table`

Comment: Thanks, this worked for calling another div on the page, but for some reason did not work for the sort-table div.  I switched it to a class and it's working great

Comment: `find("sort-table")` will look for an element named `sort-table` but `find(div.sort-table)`  will look for a div that has a class `sort-table`

Answer (score 0):

That was work for me

```
$(data).filter('div.test');
```

here is link [Use Jquery Selectors on $.AJAX loaded HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405409/use-jquery-selectors-on-ajax-loaded-html)