# Act on ajax result with jquery before append

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following ajax success function. How can I act on the result with jquery before appending it? The following code is my attempt, however, the second console statement never writes.

See the current .filter line. I base that as my latest attempt after reading and trying the different methods from here: [Use Jquery Selectors on $.AJAX loaded HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405409/use-jquery-selectors-on-ajax-loaded-html)

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#myactionlink').click(function (result)
    {
        $.ajax(this.href, {
            success: function (result)
            {
                console.log((new Date()).getTime() + ' - ' + 'result returned.');
                $(result).filter('input[name="RowId"]').each(function (i)
                {
                    var x = (i + 1).toString();
                    console.log((new Date()).getTime() + ' - ' + 'RowId: ' + x);
                    $(this).val(x);
                });
                $('#mypartial').append(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**Html Partial being returned.**

```
<div>
    <input id="RowId" name="RowId" type="text" value="">
</div>
```

### Current Inprogress Solution

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#myactionlink').click(function (result)
    {
        $.ajax(this.href, {
            success: function (result)
            {
                console.log((new Date()).getTime() + ' - ' + 'result returned.');
                var outResult = $(result);
                outResult.filter('[name="RowId"]').each(function (i)
                {
                    var x = (i + 1).toString();
                    console.log((new Date()).getTime() + ' - ' + 'RowId: ' + x);
                    $(this).val(x);
                }).end().appendTo('#mypartial');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: How sure are you that the result has an input element named "RowId"?Can you show us an example of what result is?

Comment: Because when I use $('input[name="RowId"]') instead of $(result).filter, it successfully applies the rowid. However, it does this for everyrow i have appended, not just the one I am appending, thanks. I realise I will need to have to change the function from a for each to getting the max number + 1. I am focusing on the filter part for now. The example is illogical right now.

Comment: I am adding a sample html now....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store a reference to `result`, modify it, then append it.

```
var outResult = $(result);
outResult.find('[name="RowId"]').each(...).end().appendTo("#mypartial");
```

You were actually appending the original html and not doing anything with the one you created using `$(result)`.

Comment: Kevin, I am unsure if I have implemented your suggestion successfully. i have updated my question with the latest code at the bottom.

Comment: At this point i think the problem may lie with what is being returned by result. What does result contain? Are the inputs children of a root node in result, or are you returning only inputs?

Comment: Replace `.filter` with `.find`, updating example.