# cant find div element in ajax data find

Tags: html, jquery

This is my whole **Ajax page** which is returned

```
 <!DOCTYPE div PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<div class="CareerAjaxData">Simple Div Content</div>
```

The  **jQuery script** in the **Main page** which calls this **Ajax page** is

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : url,
    data : data,
    datatype : 'html',
    success : function(ajaxdata) {
        var $tabcontent = $(ajaxdata).find('.CareerAjaxData');
        console.log($tabcontent.html());        
    }
});
```

But the output of Console gives: undefined

I get proper response from the server.
But there some problem with js I guess.

whats wrong here..??

Comment: I think your problem is that .find() matches [descendents](http://api.jquery.com/find/), while in your case ajaxData is the element your looking for.

Answer (score 1):

After wasting half a day.. I found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/405700/920271.

Yes `doctype` was a typo.. but that wasn't the problem.

Using `filter` instead of `find` helped me.!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what type of `doctype` you are using. I have never seen that before. I would try a normal

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

As far as `jQuery`, try this:

```
$('#tabcontent').load('url .CareerAjaxData');
```

Comment: actually I needed to divs to placed in to divs of the main page.. so load was not for me