# How I select only specific div from the data

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to select only specific part from the return data?

this is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[href*='delete']").click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        url = 'http://localhost'+url;

        $.ajax({
            type : 'GET',
            url : url,
            success : function(data){
                $('#table_div').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

if I use above codes it set the complete page to `#table_div`. so I need to select only that `#table_div` data form the `data`. how do I do that ?

Comment: see this, it will helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/405409/use-jquery-selectors-on-ajax-loaded-html

Comment: have you tried ? `$(data).filter('#table_div');`

Comment: if it helps you, i am putting it as answer. you can accept it as answer so it could help others too. Thanks. !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this ?

```
$(data).filter('#table_div');
$(data).find('#table_div');
```

see this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405409/use-jquery-selectors-on-ajax-loaded-html)

Hope, it will helps you. Thanks. !!

Comment: when I add .filter(), it isn't work but It work for .find() . do you have any idea?

Comment: `filter` will search through all element whereas `find` will search only in the descendent list.

Comment: this is my code$.ajax({
     type : 'GET',
     url : myurl,
     success : function(data){                $('#table_div').html($(data).filter('#table_div'));
                }
            });

Comment: Try this: `$('div').filter( $('#table_div'))` like this 
`$("div").filter( $("#unique") )` see ref http://api.jquery.com/filter/  `Filter` actually returns the items chosen in the previous selector which also match the the selector in the filter method. Is it helpful to you ?