# Pass dynamic argument into .load() / $.ajax()

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am sorry that I found what I did wrongly.. just typal mistake between the html file and txt file

First of all, I apologies to my poor English.

I am trying to get the html code inside a `div` in the external txt file dynamically through ajax by jQuery. However, I cannot get the html code in specific `div` as I expected.
Here comes my code

.html file

```
<div id="html_div_id_A">
  <div class="html_div_class">
  </div>  
</div>

<div id="html_div_id_B">
  <div class="html_div_class"> 
  </div>  
</div>
```

---

abc.txt file

```
<div id = "txt_div_id_A">
  <div class="txt_div_class">
        some content A
  </div>  
</div>

<div id = "txt_div_id_B">
  <div class="txt_div_class">
        some content B
  </div>  
</div>
```

---

.js file

```
function func(arg)
{
    var htmlDivId = $(arg).attr("id").toString()// html_div_id_A or html_div_id_B, decided in run time
    var txtDivId = htmlDivId == "html_div_id_A" ? "#txt_div_id_A" : "#txt_div_id_B";// txt_div_id_A or txt_div_id_B, decided in run time

    // What I could do now
    $(htmlDivId + " > .html_div_class").load("abc.txt #txt_id_B div");

    // What I expected to do
    $(htmlDivId + " > .html_div_class").load("abc.txt " + txtDivId + " div");
}
```

I have tried the solution that suggest in [here (Use Jquery Selectors on $.AJAX loaded HTML?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405409/use-jquery-selectors-on-ajax-loaded-html) but it does not work.
Are there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
function func(arg)
{
    var htmlDivId = $(arg).attr("id");

    //You need to assign the string value of the target id
    var txtDivId = htmlDivId == "html_div_id_A" ? 'txt_div_id_A' : 'txt_div_id_B';// txt_div_id_A or txt_div_id_B, decided in run time

    // What I expected to do
    // need to prepend # to target id
    $('#' + htmlDivId + " > .html_div_class").load("abc.txt #" + txtDivId + " div");
}
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tqnviIZxEKPk66OQKPD4?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you~ However, I did it correctly in my real code. Thank you for your contribution and I discovered my mistake already